# Asking for a bonus increase for my top performance in one-to-one performance review?

Tags: performance-reviews, bonus

I am going to have a one-to-one meeting with my manager on my yearly performance review. During the past year, some work that I have done has made a very significant contribution to the company, and my manager is well aware of that, he told me that what I have done was a very big deal in more than one private discussion with me. I am thinking of asking for a bonus increase for my work in this coming-up performance review meeting, because I am afraid that it might be too late at the bonus giving out time if the number doesn't satisfy me, however I am also afraid whether it is appropriate to ask now.

So my questions are:

1. Is it appropriate to ask for a bonus increase or tell the manager that I expect to get appreciation on the bonus for the work I have done?
2. If so, how should I ask about it or phrase to let my manager be aware what I am expecting?

Comment: Does this question address your concern? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, whatever revision you want to have in your payout, the performance review is the event to discuss about it. It does not matter at what time the payout takes place (for bonus), having a clear idea on your expectation (for the organization) and the actual amount agreed (from your side) makes things clear and leaves no room for a surprise at a later point of time.

> So my questions are:
>
> - *Is it appropriate to ask for a bonus increase or tell the manager that I expect to get appreciation on the bonus for the work I have done?*

Yes, based on your contribution and value add to the organization, you can negotiate your remuneration- be it bonus or basic salary.

> - *If so, how should I ask about it or phrase to let my manager be aware what I am expecting?*

Be ready with the performance review points.

- Have a list of the targets you had.
- List your contributions and how much value add you bring in for the team and the organization.
- Based on that evaluation, discuss the revision you'd expect.

Comment: +1. I would add, be very polite, but direct. "I'd like to share in the company's success with my work. If a bonus is available I'd like it". And, be patient. I sometimes takes managers a while to get approval.